# How to use rxjs limit click button once in 2s ？

Tags: angular, rxjs

For click button once in 2 seconds, what should I do? Rxjs has many operators like throttleTime.But the grammar is :

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .throttleTime(1000)
  .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
  .subscribe(count => console.log(`Clicked ${count} times`));
```

I use angular and Rxjs.The grammar is :

```
 // html
<button (click) = "clickMe()">

// ts
clickMe(){
 alert('yes!!!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular way, get `button` reference by `@ViewChild` decorator. And in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook:

```
@ViewChild('btn', { read: ElementRef }) button: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

   ...

    Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
      .throttleTime(2000) // change from one second to two
      .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
      .subscribe(count => console.log(`Clicked ${count} times`));
}
```

**template:**

```
<button #btn>Hello</button>
```

[throttleTime docs.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime)

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-use-rxjs-limit-click-button-once-in-2s)

Answer (score 0):

The suitable operator here may be

`debounceTime(2000)`

When multiple clicks occur, if there comes a break (2s in this case), then the last click will be activated. This is the desired behavior in usecases like the one that you described.

`throttleTime()` just suspends the clicks for the specified amount of time.